# How do I use NPM to check packages locally, only current vs wanted. Don't to try and fetch latest version

Tags: node.js, npm, githooks

I'm using 'npm oudated' command, the only problem is that its a bit slow because it actually figures out the latest version of npm packages as well.

Ideally I just want to know if there is a missing package locally and run npm install if there is a missing packages.

I created this script as a post-checkout githook, is there a better way to check if you are missing packages that are in your package.json?

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    missingPackage = false;

return new Promise((resolve) => {
        exec('npm outdated --json', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            resolve(JSON.parse(stdout));
        })
    })
    .then((packageJson) => {
        for (const x of Object.keys(packageJson)) {
            if (packageJson[x].location === '' ) {
                missingPackage = true;
            }
        }
    })
    .then(() => {
        if (missingPackage) {
            console.log('\nHello, you are missing some packages so we are going to install them....');
            exec('npm install', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                console.log(stdout);
            })
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see anything in the NPM documentation so I just created this. Takes less than a second to check if you are missing packages

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const exec = require('child_process').exec,
    fs = require('fs'),
    packageJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('package.json', 'utf8')),
    dependenciesPackages = Object.keys(packageJson.dependencies),
    devDependenciesPackages = Object.keys(packageJson.devDependencies),
    allNpmPackages = dependenciesPackages.concat(devDependenciesPackages);

// Checking if any packages are missing
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    for (const [idx, npmPackage] of allNpmPackages.entries()) {
        fs.readFile(`node_modules/${npmPackage}/package.json`, 'utf8', function(err) {
            if (err && err.code === 'ENOENT') {
                resolve(true);
            } else if (idx === allNpmPackages.length - 1) {
                resolve(false);
            }
        });
    }
})
// If packages are missing then run npm install
.then((isMissingPackages) => {
    if (isMissingPackages) {
        console.log('\nHello, you are missing some packages so we are going to install them....'); // eslint-disable-line no-console
        exec('npm install', (error, stdout) => {
            console.log(stdout); // eslint-disable-line no-console
        });
    }
});
```